# Filters & Rules layout

Tags: popup, filter

I am working on a cryptocurrency trading application and got stuck with filter popups.

First one is for "Bases", which filters a list of trading signals.
[image]

Second one is the filter for quick scanner, which shows a list of markets that have a significant change in price in a small time period
[image]

Would love to hear any ideas or suggestions on how to make these 2 look & work better as well as create a consistent, similar design for both

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lack of hierarchy that makes the screen overwhelming. It requires quite some work and knowledge of user needs to achieve it. Font size and weight is where I would start. Also some borders to separate the modules.